# How to remove part of file name using a regex expression?

Tags: regex, powershell, file-rename, rename-item-cmdlet

I have a bunch of files names as such:

```
Belinda Carlisle - Mad About You-Xmdtjwmr9zq.mp4
Air Supply - All Out of Love-Jwdzeumnrmi.mp4
Blue Savannah Song - Erasure-Wxoutwk8jv8.mp4
Breathe - How Can I Fall (1988)-Pwz4erdjzra.mp4
```

I would like to be able to trim out the suffix of random characters. I got some help with formulating a regex, and I slapped together a two-liner in PowerShell, and it works. The only caveat is that I have to first filter by the regex before piping it to 'rename-item', otherwise, it adds two extensions to the filename like
Belinda Carlisle -Mad About You.mp4.mp4 for the filenames that are 'clean' - aka without the extraneous suffix.

Can this be done another way so that I don't have to filter by matching regex and achieve the same thing? Not being nitpicky, just curious.

Here's the expression I cobbled together.

```
Get-ChildItem $targetpath -file | 
where-object {$_.name -match "-[a-z\d]+(?=\.[^.]+$)"} | 
ForEach-Object {
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ('{0}{1}' -f ($_.Name -replace "-[a-z\d]+(?=\.[^.]+$).*","$1"), $_.Extension )
}
```

Comment: How about basename instead of name?

Comment: FYI Instead of using the MD code fencing, use the provide SO code formatting tools. I've already edited this for you fo this post.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex can be simplified to just this.

```
Clear-Host
(@'
Belinda Carlisle - Mad About You-Xmdtjwmr9zq.mp4
Air Supply - All Out of Love-Jwdzeumnrmi.mp4
Blue Savannah Song - Erasure-Wxoutwk8jv8.mp4
Breathe - How Can I Fall (1988)-Pwz4erdjzra.mp4
'@) -replace '-[\w]([^.]+)'

# Results
<#
Belinda Carlisle - Mad About You.mp4
Air Supply - All Out of Love.mp4
Blue Savannah Song - Erasure.mp4
Breathe - How Can I Fall (1988).mp4
#>
```

Comment: ***'Metzli_Tonaltzintli'***, as written, what you have will error with ```Rename-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be evaluated 
without input.```.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem $targetpath -Filter '*-*-*' -File | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '-[\w]([^.]+)' }` worked fine for me.  Not sure why that would error for you.

Answer (score 0):

Offering an alternate solution to RegEx, you can use the string methods against the `BaseName` property then concatenating the result to the `Extension`.

```
Get-ChildItem $targetpath -Filter '*-*-*' -File | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.BaseName.Substring(0,$_.BaseName.LastIndexOf('-')) + $_.Extension }
```

Answer (score 0):

- As [js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) suggests, you can simplify your task by operating only on the `.BaseName` property of each input file, re-appending the filename extension after any potential transformation with (`+ $_.Extension`)
- It is both conceptually simpler and more efficient to use a [delay-bind script block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) in your [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) call, which allows piping input *directly* to it.
- If a given file's name happens to be "clean" already, `Rename-Item` will - fortunately - be a *quiet no-op*; that is, if the `-NewName` argument is the same as the current file name, no action is taken.

```powershell
Get-ChildItem $targetpath -File |
  Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.BaseName -replace '-[a-z\d]+$') + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>